# ¿Cómo usar control + v en git-bash?

Tags: git-bash

En git bash no me funciona el <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> de toda la vida.
También he probado con <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes pegar:

- Haciendo click con la rueda del ratón o el botón del medio del ratón (middle-click)
- Pulsando <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>
- Haciendo click con en botón derecho en la terminal y haciendo click en "Paste"

Dicho eso, es verdad que git-bash falla bastante a menudo. Si no te deja pegar con ninguno de esos métodos, hay veces que no queda más remedio que reiniciarlo para que te deje pegar.